# SharePoint 2013 - YouTube embed full screen not working in IE 11

Tags: 2013, video, ie

Youtube embed iframe full screen option is not working in IE 11 . I have done some troubleshooting and below are some key facts.

1. Full screen option works if I change the compatibility mode to Edge. But SP Seattle masterpage defaults to IE 10 compatibility mode and full screen does not work
2. I have tried allowfullscreen attribute but no luck with IE 11.
3. The full screen option works in Chrome and other browsers.
   4.Another interesting observation from a user is that this used to work before.
4. Tried same thing in SharePoint online and same result in IE 11.

Have anyone of you experienced this problem in SharePoint lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with IE11.  I had to modify both master pages (Seattle & Oslo) to change compatibility mode to "edge" (current version):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

SharePoint (2013, at least) strips out the "allowfullscreen" tag, whether it's via Edit Source (HTML Source) or Embed Code (Snippet) or Content Editor Web Part (where it says "click here to add add new content").  I couldn't get it to stick (not even `allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"`).

However, SharePoint doesn't tamper with embedded files when using a *Content Link* in the **Content Editor Web Part**.  So, set your *Content Link* to a text file (any extension): "../SiteAssets/inc/PageName.html" (I used ".html" so that Visual Studio Code would use HTML highlighting.)

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?rel=0" width="100%" height="800" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: it works when adding the embed into a html file and referring it as a CEWP